# Hamiltonian path problem vs other NPC problems

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, np-complete, hamiltonian-path

If we can solve the Hamiltonian path in time $O(n^4)$ then you can solve any other NPC problem in $O(n^4)$ time. Is it true of false? I think it is false, even tho Hamiltonian path problem in NPC it doesnt mean that all NPC problems will be solved in the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. There might be an $NP$-complete problem that can only be translated into Hamiltonian path problem in $\Omega(n^{10})$ time, for instance. In which case an $\Omega(n^{10})$ translation and an $O(n^4)$ solution gives a total time of $\Omega(n^{10})$. The only thing you can be certain of is that the final time is bounded by a *polynomial*.

Comment: Small nitpick: the use of $O(\cdot)$ vs. $\Omega(\cdot)$. I guess you meant the reduction takes $\Omega(n^{10})$ time?

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, of course.

Comment: @Arthur can you please edit  your answer, I get confused now where are you talking about the reduction takes Ω(n^10) time? :(

Comment: @ClementC. I get confused now where are you talking about the reduction takes Ω(n^10) time? :(

Comment: Well, it is *conceivable* that any reduction from say 3SAT to Hamiltonian path "could have to take roughly $n^{10}$ time," which means that the reduction is $\Omega(n^{10})$. It is $\Omega$ and not $O$ since it'd be a *lower bound* on the time complexity of the reduction, not an *upper bound*.